# Why can't I shoot in raw on my galaxy s7 after upgrading to nougat?

Tags: samsung, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s7, 7.1-nougat

I recently upgraded to nougat through a T-Mobile service update and now all of my camera apps say that my camera doesn't support raw capture. Is there a way to fix this? If not, is there a way to revert back to marshmallow without losing all of my data or voiding my warranty?

Comment: Download stock firmware from Sammobile and revert

Comment: @Suncatcher You sure that you could downgrade? Bootloader is likely upgraded already and blocking downgrades.

Comment: Bootloader is perfectly flashable via Odin as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can shoot in raw. They just changed where it is placed on the Nougat upgrade. It is the last option under picture size and can only be accessed when using the pro mode.